# Homology commutes with direct product of chain complexes. Direct proof in a module category.

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

This is an attempt to prove that direct product of chain complexes commutes with homology (exercise in Weibel's book).  I've had some success since I've proved that $Z_n(\prod_{\alpha \in A} C_{\alpha \cdot}) = \prod_{\alpha \in A} Z_n(C_{\alpha \cdot})$. In other words that direct product commutes with the $n$-cycles of a chain complex.  My attempt at the $n$-boundary part:

$B_n(\prod_{\alpha \in A} C_{\alpha \cdot}) = \text{im } d_{n+1} = \{\prod_{\alpha\in A}d_{\alpha, n+1}(x_{\alpha}) : x_{\alpha} \in C_{\alpha, n+1}\} = \prod_{\alpha} B_n(C_{\alpha \cdot})$.  The last step I thinks is clear.

Now how do I throw together the rest of the proof (showing that direct product therefore commutes with homology $H_n$)?  Except in this case the two product formulas are only isomorphic is what Weibel's book seems to imply, where as the formulas we found above for cycles and boundaries have equality.

By the way, these are chain complexes of $R$-modules.

Comment: It seems like the two homology formulas would be equal, but then why in the book are they just isomorphic?

Comment: I think your proof is almost complete: you just have to use the fact that in a module category, direct product is an exact functor to finish it. By the way, it is here that you only get isomorphism and not equality. Your proof uses elements and explicit description of direct products in a module category but cannot be used for general abelian category (which is the setup of Weibel's exercise) since the Freyd's embedding does not preserves infinite products. See my answer to your question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To treat this exercise in the most general setup, you can say that in a category in which limits exists and the limit functor is exact (AB4* means exactly that since limit is a right adjoint functor so it is always left exact, see the Appendix in Weibel's book), the homology functor of any degree does commute with direct product. Fortunately the category of $R$-modules does verify AB4* (and AB4 actually).
The proof is simple: take the following exact sequence $$0\to \ker d_n\to \text{im}\ d_{n+1}\to H_n(A_n^{i})\to 0$$ where $A^{i}$ is a complex for $i\in I$. Apply the exact functor direct product. You immediately get what you want since by exactness direct product commutes with $\ker$ (always) and $\text{im}$ (AB4*).

Comment: Instead of posting a duplicate answer, try to get a duplicate post closed. =)

Comment: (I think the other post might be about direct sums, but the proof is almost the same.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff well, it is a dual answer to a dual question ... I am bit lazy sorry about that

Comment: I guess we should start considering closing coduplicates. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff so the question is: should dual question be closed as duplicates? You should develop a discussion about dual duplicates right? =)

Comment: Yes, that's my point.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff The good side of this is that votes to coquestion give copoints that add to points. That is why I humbly request not to close this coquestion then I can get the full covotes benefit. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @brunoh, surely you mean $0 \rightarrow \text{im } d_{n+1} \rightarrow \ker d_n \rightarrow H_n(A_n) \rightarrow 0$, or am I confused?